# Duda con cambio de version laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Que tal amigos, me encuentro con pequeño problema, tengo un proyecto en laravel con versión php 7.2, pero el hosting donde lo voy a alojar solo tiene la versión 7.1.3, que podría pasar si realizo esta migración? habrían muchos problemas con el código?

Saludos

Comment: En la documentación de PHP y Laravel está todo.

Comment: Es importante realices tus preguntas en base a [ask], como esta formulada tu pregunta parece requerir de opiniones, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La versión 5.6 justamente necesita 7.1.3 o superior, por lo que todo ira bien.
Puedes encontrar mas documentación [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade)

**EDITO**: Si lo que te preocupa es migrar solo la version de PHP tampoco pasa nada por el framework

> (Laravel 5.5 requires PHP 7.0.0 or higher)

Pero, esto no es del todo real, dado que **laravel** no te dará problemas, pero si usaste `helpers` que solo están en ciertas versiones de **PHP** en tu código, si que puede ocasionar problemas, como es el caso del comparador `??` para dar valores a los nulos.

Comment: Igualmente la respuesta esta en el mismo enlace, "Laravel 5.5 requires PHP 7.0.0 or higher."

Comment: No respondí con un enlace, di la respuesta y puse el enlace del cual se puede verificar. igualmente, ya lo tienes editado.

Comment: ayúdanos respondiendo únicamente preguntas basadas en [ask] o que demuestran investigación por parte del OP,  veo que respondes continuamente a este tipo de preguntas que al final únicamente pueden ser útiles a quien pregunta pero no para la comunidad, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys♦ Respondo a todas las preguntas que no tienen respuesta siempre y cuando tengan un mínimo de lógica. Todo el mundo tienen un inicio por el que estar mas que perdido y si revisas mis comentarios veras que no solo pongo respuestas, sino que en los que veo que no tienen ni pies ni cabezas les dejo un comentario para que corrijan la pregunta y luego responderlas.